# Find all local extremums of $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^{2}+x+1}$ and decide if these are global extremums

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, curves

Did I do everything correctly?

> Find all local extremums of the following function and decide if these
>   are global extremums (i.e. maxima or rather minima of the function on
>   its entire domain) or not:
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto\frac{x}{x^{2}+x+1} \in \mathbb{R}$

Check behavior of function $f$ for $x\rightarrow +- \infty$  (because maybe there will be global extremums but they could be the limit..):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=-0$$

$$f'(x) = -\frac{x^{2}+1}{(x^{2}+x+1)^{2}}$$

$$f'(x)=0$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$0=-\frac{x^{2}+1}{(x^{2}+x+1)^{2}}$$

$$0=\frac{x^{2}+1}{(x^{2}+x+1)^{2}}$$

$$0=x^{2}+1$$

$$x^{2}=-1$$

There is no result which means that the function $f$ hasn't got any extremums.

Comment: Check your derivative again.

Comment: $f(x)$ is defined everywhere and tends to $0$ for $x\rightarrow \pm\infty$. It must have at least one global extremum, in fact it has $2$, a global minimum and a global maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your limit as of $f$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ is all good, however, your derivative has a little snag in it. Using the quotient rule we have $$f'(x) = \frac{(x^2 + x+1) - x(2x +1)}{(x^2 + x+1)^2} = \frac{1 - x^2}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$ and so $f'$ vanishes precisely at $x = \pm 1$, giving $f(-1) = 1$ a global maximum and $f(1) = \frac{1}{3}$ a global minimum.

---

Note: Since your $f$ is defined everywhere and tends to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ it must have at least one global extrema. Think of the shape of the graph or the IVT for intuition and rigor respectively.

Comment: Just one question.
To show that one point is an extremum and the other one is a minimum, we have to use $f''(x)$ and check if it's larger / greater than zero...
That would be very time consuming in an exam. Would you say it's a must or can we look at the results (here: $1$ and $\frac{1}{3}$), insert them in $f$ and check which point lies higher. That point which lies higher than the other one is the maximum. Would it work like that or is my idea completely wrong?

Comment: You can also simply note that $f'$ changes from positive to negative at $x=-1$ making that a maximum and goes from negative to positive at $x=1$ making that a minimum.